# Escaping issues with backslashes and double quotes

Tags: c#, sharepoint, escaping

In sharepoint in order to have a field translated I have to modify one attribute which is called schemaxml.

When I read it using c# the code I get is something like this:

```
  string schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = recurrentField.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
  int startIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("DisplayName=\"")) + 1;
  int endIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
  int substringLength = endIndex - startIndex;
  string value = @"DisplayName=\" + schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
  schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Replace(value, @"DisplayName=\$Resources:SPNLMeetings,Field_Recurrent_Name");
  recurrentField.SchemaXml = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
  recurrentField.Update();
```

The values is not being changed.

[image]

Comment: May you post some example input? (whatever "schemaXmlWithResourceTokens" is)

Comment: Ensure that `schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength)` actually returns the value you are looking for.

Comment: please seee the screenshot. the 3rd value in the watch value is the input

Comment: @SteveKonves Its not, thats the question in first place, its not being replaced because escaping problems, look at the screenshot. I want to replace Value IN schemaXmlwithresourceTokens by $Resources:SPNLMeetings,Field_Recurrent_Name

Comment: I think your problem is in the line where you set `string value`.  How it is currently written, `value` is `DisplayName=\ ` but `schemaXmlWithResourceTokens` contains `DisplayName="`.  (See answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string value = "DisplayName=\"" + schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
```

The difference being `"DisplayName=\""` instead of `@"DisplayName=\"`